# Is there some security software using Linux Security Module?

Tags: linux, security, linux-security-module

LSM(Linux Security Module) was used in kernel 2.6. Now kernel comes to 4.x and I can't figure out if there are still some using LSM? Does the latest kernel give up the support for LSM?

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules) the kernel still uses LSM. Modules like AppArmor are implemented on top of LSM. So yes, it is still used and modules that take advantage of it do exist.